# Best way to handle information from the server

Tags: architecture, xna, client-server

I'm developing an xna-game and have run into some problems. I started with just getting information from the server in the main loop like this:

```
player.X = client.GetInt32();
player.Y = client.GetInt32();
player.IsShooting = client.GetBoolean();
```

After a while I moved this code to a separate class: ServerLayer.

At first ServerLayer contained the player instance, but after a while ServerLayer had references to Map and Bombs and a bunch of other stuff. So I decided to pass the objects that needed the information from the server directly into the method like this:

In main loop:

```
serverLayer.GetPosition(player);
```

In ServerLayer:

```
public void GetPosition(Player player) 
{
    player.X = client.GetInt32();
    player.Y = client.GetInt32();
    player.IsShooting = client.GetBoolean();
}
```

Is this the right way to do it? Some of the methods (GetInit etc.) take a lot of arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a right way to me, the only thing I see is the name of the method, maybe it should be UpdatePosition instead of GetPosition.

You use sockets to transfer data from client to server ? If you send a packet at each GetPosition call (you call it in main loop so at each frame) it may be very laggy on a production environement

Maybe you could call it once every 80/100ms